# Slack - Not able to create action on interactive button click

Tags: php

Below is the php code which i have used to create buttons

```
$channel  = "#test";
$message  = 'Would you like to play a game?';

//To create the buttons
$g8_buttons = array([
"name" => "QR",
"text" => "QR",
"type" => "button",
"value" => "QR"
],[
"name"=> "URL",
"text"=> "URL",
"type"=> "button",
"value"=> "URL"
],[
"name"=> "Flyer",
"text"=> "Flyer",
"type"=> "button",
"value"=> "Flyer"
]
);                                                          


$data = array(
'channel'     => $channel,
"text" => "What would you like to have?",
"attachments" => array([
"text" => "Choose the below options",
"fallback" => "You are unable to choose a game",
"callback_id" => "wopr_game",
"color" => "#3AA3E3",
"attachment_type" => "default",
"actions" => $g8_buttons
])
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init("https://hooks.slack.com/services/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");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Execute CURL
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have given the image of the output i get on slack
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sX1n.png)

I am not able to get any action on click of buttons.
I created the slack app giving a https url under interactive messages option but there is not POST json coming to that url when i am clicking the button. Please help. Thanks in advance.
I get the Slackbot message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyTQY.png)

Comment: Thanks for the Slack credentials :)

Comment: Have you checked the Slackbot Framework at https://github.com/iranianpep/slackbot? It supports message actions and might be helpful.